# Laravel Echo How to take an action when the users joins a channel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

Using Laravel 5.5, vue.js and laravel echo.

I want to apply an instruction that something happens whenever the user, that is attempting to join the channel, has a successful join.

In my case, if it was a successful join it will add an object to an array.

```
Echo.join('chat' + e.thread.id)
    .listen('ThreadPosted', (e) => {
         console.log("ThreadPosted");
     });
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: AFAIK the listen callback is only called when you join successfully or do you want to listen for other users to join the channel?

Comment: I want something to happen whenever the user that is attempting to join the channel successfully joins. The listen callback is when you have already joined the channel and you listen for any Event broadcasted.

Comment: Under the configuration header of [this link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#broadcasting-events), you can see that `Echo` has a `socketId` you might be able to use that to check for an active connection

Comment: Checked documentation and tried but nothing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method "here" :

```
Echo.join('channel')
.here((users) => {
    // client has joined successfully
 })
.listen('Event', callback );
```

As mentioned in [Laravel echo documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting#presence-channels) :

> The "here" callback will be executed immediately once the channel is joined successfully, and will receive an array containing the user information for all of the other users currently subscribed to the channel.

There are also two other callbacks available, "joining" and "leaving"

> The "joining" method will be executed when a new user joins a channel, while the "leaving" method will be executed when a user leaves the channel.

```
Echo.join('channel')
.joining((user) => {
    // a user has joined.
})
.leaving((user) => {
    // a user has left.
});
```

Bear in mind that all these methods are available for Presence Channels, which is mostly used for chat applications.